# Codeigniter Complex MySQL Query - Removing Backticks - is it a Security Issue?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, backticks

I'm trying to build a MySQL query to return appropriate search results, by examining several different database fields. For example if a user searches "plumber leeds", if a business had 'leeds' in the 'city' field and the word 'plumber' as part of their name, I would want that search result to be returned.

User searches could contain several words and are unpredictable. I'm currently achieving what I need by exploding the search term, trimming it and using it to compile a complex search query to return all relevant results.

I'm storing this complex query in a variable and using Codeigniter's Active Record to run the query.

```
$this->db->where($compiled_query, null, false);
```

What I'm concerned about is that I'm not protecting the query with backticks and I'm unsure if this is a security issue. I have XSS Clean enabled but still not sure if this is ok.

According to CI's user manual:
$this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

Source: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Some info about how I compile the query here in a separate question. I'm aware mysql_real_escape_string is about to be deprecated and isn't a catch-all, hence part of my concern about this method.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321642/codeigniter-active-record-sql-query-of-multiple-words-vs-multiple-database-fi

Any help appreciated

Comment: can you add some more detail, especially about how you compose the query?

Comment: Thanks I've posted a link within the question which shows this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say you're absolutely "safe", because you're never technically safe if you accept user input in a SQL query (even if you've manipulated it... when there's a will, there's a way).

Once you relinquish control over what is given to your application, you must be very careful how you deal with that data so that you don't open yourself up to an injection attack.

XSS Clean will help with `POST` or cookie data -- it does not run automatically on `GET` variables. I would manually run `$data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);` on the input if it's from the `GET` array.

Comment: I'm using it on POST data but I'm sure this answer will help some others. I think @jmadsen 's answer was also helpful but accepting this as the answer for the extra detail. My user inputted search terms will not be back-ticked either so I thought perhaps this is where the security issue would come from - someone could include their own back ticks in the search term to escape mine?

Comment: "escaping" backing ticks makes no sense - the most that would ever do is cause your query to fail.

Answer (score 3):

Backticks have nothing to do with security. They are really just a way to "stringify" your field and table names, so that you could use a field called `datatype` for example and not have ti conflict with mysql keywords

You are safe